# Could we make our own CNContainer? swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-contacts-api, swift3, cncontact

In this below image, google and yahoo could get their own CNContainer.

[image]

Could we make our own CNContainer like gmail and yahoo in these screenshot? If i could, how to do this?

Comment: Hi, did you find any resource on this topic? Apple docu https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts introduces the concept of Unified Contacts, but it does not say anything about how to develop a "social account provider". I did not find even a small piece of information regarding this. Net is just only full of long fancy articles about fetching, creating and updating a contact in the default `CNContainer`. So far, I'm on implementing my own online CardDAV server.

Comment: @Štěpán Did you ever figure out how to create a CNContainer? Where do I start learning how to set up a CardDAV? Does that require our own server, or can I do that on an iOS device locally?

Comment: @DanielBrower I gave up implementing contacts back in 2019. I didn't find the right resources for CNContacts and own CardDAV server would have been to complicated to implement and point the users to. There are though free or paid implementations of CardDAV. I don't think it can run locally on iOS.

Comment: @Štěpán Aaw. That's too bad. Thank you for your help.